# Convert array to hash with custom format

Tags: ruby, arrays

Can somebody help me to convert the following array to a hash with the following format?

**Array**

`[["0", {"checkbox_2"=>"on"}], ["2", {"checkbox_1"=>"on"}]]`

**Hash**

```
search=>{"checkbox_2"=>"on", "checkbox_1"=>"on"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = [["0", {"checkbox_2"=>"on"}], ["2", {"checkbox_1"=>"on"}]] 
hash = Hash[arr.flatten.select{|e| e.is_a? Hash}.collect{|e| e.to_a.flatten}]
=> {"checkbox_2"=>"on", "checkbox_1"=>"on"}
```

Comment: this way would be ok if the hash appeared in any position but if it's always in the second position, well, it's unnecessarily convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

```
xs = [["0", {"checkbox_2"=>"on"}], ["2", {"checkbox_1"=>"on"}]]
search = {:search => xs.map { |n, h| h }.inject(:merge)}
# {:search=>{"checkbox_2"=>"on", "checkbox_1"=>"on"}}
```

Comment: How about `{ :search => xs.map(&:last).inject(:merge) }`?

Comment: @Michael: yeah, or (&:second) on Rails. Thing is, when getting from pairs I feel it's more clear to de-structure (in other languages those elements would be tuples, not arrays).